# Is there a site like Jetsetter for France/Europe?

Tags: budget, europe, online-resources, hotels, paris

I use [Jetsetter](http://www.jetsetter.com) frequently for hotel deals in the US and sometimes abroad.  I know Gilt (Jetsetter's owner) is loosely based on [Vente Privee](http://en.vente-privee.com/vp4/login/portal.ashx), according to this [NY Times](http://dealbook.nytimes.com/2011/02/18/gilt-groupe-chief-considering-i-p-o-in-2012/) article anyway.

> Its founders were inspired by a European counterpart, Vente Privee, which is based in Paris and widely considered the pioneer in this market.

I was wondering if there was a site like Jetsetter for Europe, specifically Paris.  Jetsetter is great for US deals and I would love to see another site that has the same breadth of sales in European cities.  I don't *think* Vente Privee does a hotel/travel site but I could be wrong.

EDIT: Sorry I wasn't more clear about what Jetsetter was.  It's a site that has "flash sales" usually lasting a week or so of discounts on certain hotels.  They are typically higher end but there are some more affordable options as well.  The one thing I do like about the site is they do in depth reviews and publish great photos of the property.  The site is members only, but all you have to do is sign up.

To address the difference between booking.com, Jetsetter isn't an aggregator of hotel prices, it has it's own list of hotels, and the sale prices on their site are typically lower than the prices that a booking.com, or kayak.com can find (not always! but the majority of the time).

Comment: Since I'm not a member, is this a 'cheap deals' site or a site for more 'exclusive' or 'high-end' hotels?

Comment: What makes Jetsetter different from Booking.com and Hotels.com?

Answer (score 2):

I use [TravelZoo](http://www.travelzoo.com/uk/) - they have a 'top 20' weekly deals newsletter, plus flash deals, for generally sites in Europe.  Some incredible offerings in there sometimes.